# Run npm test only once, not autowatch

Tags: github, npm, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I just created this npm based Ionic test on my GitHUb repo

```
name: Ionic test

on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
    - 'v*'
    - master

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [10.x]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
    - run: npm install
    - run: npm test
```

but after it finishes with

```
TOTAL: 33 SUCCESS
TOTAL: 33 SUCCESS
```

the workflow does not stop. It keeps spinning and the status of the PR stays

```
Some checks haven’t completed yet
```

I tried removing the `// autoWatch: true,` in `karma.conf.js` but it still keeps spinning on both CLI and GitHub. Not sure how else to make `npm test` run only once.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solved it in `karma.conf.js` with

```
    autoWatch: false,
    browsers: ['ChromeHeadless'],
    singleRun: true,
```

GitLab now finishes my thing.